# How to find all up-value symbols related its object

Tags: upvalues, variable

Suppose I set a series up-value for a rectangle like:

```
rectangle[long] ^= 10;
rectangle[width] ^= 12;
rectangle[height] ^= 28;
```

How to find all of the symbol about the rectangle?The `Names` and the `Information` seem to cannot do this?

[image]

Comment: I do not think that this is practical to do. Since these definitions are not associated with `rectangle`, you would have the check the `UpValues` of *every existing symbol* to see if they contain `rectangle`.  This is not very practical and would only work if you restrict your search to a smaller set of symbols (e.g. ``Names["Global`*"]``).

Comment: @Szabolcs Maybe you mean ``Cases[UpValues /@ ToExpression[Names["`*"]], 
 HoldPattern[rectangle[x_]] :> x, Infinity]``

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Please correct the wording because you don't have a set of up-values  for `rectangle` you have up-values for `long/width/height`.

Comment: @Kuba I mean ***for a rectangle***.And actually I do searched my all vocabulary but just write an **object**. :)

Comment: @yode `UpSet` usage - "assigns rhs to be the value of lhs, and associates the assignment with **symbols that occur at level one** in lhs. " - which clearly indicates we are not talking about `rectangle`.

Comment: @yode Do you think `Names` or `Information` *should* be able to do this?  To me it seems similar to (but of course distinct from) asking "can I find all the symbols whose downvalues are of the form `_[ ..., someSymbolOrExpression, ... ]`?"  Note in particular that you can do something like `h_[ foo ] ^= bar` -- `h_` will match any head, so your question would be ill-defined in a case like that.  So use cases like yours are just a special case of the full power of upset.  Another example might be `(rectangle|square)[foo]^=post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [remind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139014/how-to-find-all-up-value-symbols-related-its-object#comment375413_139014) of [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)

```
UpValuesSymbols[symbol_] := 
 Cases[Quiet[UpValues /@ ToExpression[Names["`*"]]], 
  HoldPattern[symbol[x_]] :> HoldForm[symbol[x]], Infinity]

UpValuesSymbols[rectangle]
```

> {rectangle[height],rectangle[long],rectangle[width]}